# Launch other application and get object of instance

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, reference, mono

Say I have two or more applications in Visual Studio. They are both Windows forms. Application1 has a listbox. Is it possible, without referencing the other projects, to launch the other applications from the location where their executable file is, and get some form of reference or object of that instance, so from Application1 I can close it, or perform actions on it such as maximize/minimize? Thanks.

Comment: @B.K. - you are definitely correct.  But there are more polite ways to get that message across.  You can tell that TheRyan is new to Stack Overflow from his Rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can launch another process using the [System.Diagnostics.Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can use [Process.Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to end a process.

You can use Win32 to [enumerate windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of other processes and [minimize or maximize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) them. Check out [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/) for pinvoke signatures for common Win32 APIs, for example [ShowWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ShowWindow.html).

You would need some form of inter-process communication for more fine-grained control, for which there are many options from [WCF](http://gorillacoding.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/using-wcf-for-inter-process-communication/) or [.Net Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.remoting.channels.ipc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) down to [named pipes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/871044)  or [sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).